# Como pegar o ano atual no ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, query, data

Preciso pegar o ano anual no ORACLE, mas so sei pegar a data atual, assim:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

Tem como manipular isso pra pegar so o Ano?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A função [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) permite extrair as diferentes partes de um campo ou variável que contém data, hora ou um intervalo.

Para obter a data atual, use o trecho `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)`, como na *query* de exemplo:

```sql
select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) from dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando to_char:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') from dual;
```

Comment: Nessa situação haveria algum problema ao comparar o resultado com algum numero? Por exemplo se essa query retornar "2014", ao usar o operador < comparando ao numero 300 qual seria o resultado?

Comment: Usando os 4y YYYY retorna 2014, por exemplo se comparar com um número converte automaticamente. To_char(sysdate,'yyyy') < 2015 retorna true.